# create a dictionary with an array of dictionaries

Tags: objective-c, json, dictionary

Noob here. I recently started working with objective C, and currently I am stuck with dictionary concept. I want to create a json object as shown below:

```
{"UserData": {
              "Name": Mike Smith,
              "Age": 32,
              "category": [1,2,3],
              "Weekly Data": [
                               {"Monday" : [1.0,2.0,3.0]},
                               {"Tuesday": [1.0,2.0,3.0]}
                             ]
              }
}
```

I wrote the following piece of code which doesn't give the desired result. I wonder if someone could help me.

```
    -(NSString*)populateUserPreferences
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *categorydata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *weeklydata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0;i<4; i++) 
    {
        [categorydata addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }


        NSMutableArray *mondaydata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            [mondaydata addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:j]];
        }

        NSMutableArray *tuesdaydata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            [tuesdaydata addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:j]];
        }


      NSDictionary *monday  = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:mondaydata];
      NSDictionary *tuesday = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:tuesdaydata];

        [weeklydata addObject: monday  ];
        [weeklydata addObject: tuesday ];

    }

    [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:"Mike Smith"] forKey:@"Name"];
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:32.0] forKey:@"Age"];

    [dict setObject:categorydata forKey:@"category"];
    [dict setObject:weeklydata forKey:@"Weekly Data"];

    NSString * userdata = [dict JSONRepresentation];
    NSLog(request);

    NSDictionary *userdataJson = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:dict forKey:@"userData"];

    return [userdataJson JSONRepresentation];
}
```

Thanks in advance for looking into it.

Apoorva

Comment: What *is* the expected result? What's the result you're getting instead?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is when creating the monday and tuesday dictionary.

```
// mondaydata & tuesday is just array.
NSDictionary *monday  = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:mondaydata];
NSDictionary *tuesday = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:tuesdaydata];
```

This code is mistake since you did not assign the dictionary properly (where is the key for the dictionary?). Instead you should do:

```
NSDictionary *mondayDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[mondayDict setObject:mondaydata forKey:"Monday"];
NSDictionary *tuesdayDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[tuesdayDict setObject:tuesdaydata forKey:"Tuesday"];
```

Then you can add mondayDict and tuesdayDict to your array weeklydata.

ps. just a note, name your variable meaningfully. For example, mondaydata is not descriptive enough. You should use mondayArr for example. To easily identify it is an array. Just a normal coding practice to share.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary * dict = @{@"UserData": @{
                                @"Name": @"Mike Smith",
                                @"Age": @32,
                                @"category": @[@1,@2,@3],
                                @"Weekly Data": @[
                                        @{@"Monday" : @[@1.0,@2.0,@3.0]},
                                        @{@"Tuesday": @[@1.0,@2.0,@3.0]}
                                        ]
                                }
                        };
NSError * error = nil;
NSData * data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    // Do what you want
}
```